# Eclipse: Show Annotation from Previous Revision

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm using Eclipse with Subversion and I've found the Show Annotation feature to be quite helpful. What I want to do now is this: suppose I find a certain line that was changed in a certain revision. I want to see what the file looked like in the revision before that one - including annotations. I don't see anything in the right click menu that would let me do that. Is there another way?

(Sorry if this seems obvious, I've just switched over from NetBeans which has this feature up-front and center)

I'm working in the Java EE perspective, if it matters, and dealing with Java and JavaScript source files.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, if you cannot do it directly, you need to combine the Annotation view with the **[History view](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/history_view.php)** for that file (if you are using [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/)).

[image: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/images/history_view.png]

you can "Link with editor and selection", in order for that view to display the right history, find your version and previous version there, and:

- "Compare current with 'selected'" to see the delta with the current version
- "Compare with Previous State": to see the delta between the version you found in the Annotation View and its previous version
- or even [revert to that version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63185/6309) if you need to

Comment: I'm not quite following here. I enabled "Link Editor with Selection" but that didn't seem to do anything that I could see. I also see a "Show Annotation" on the right-click menu of the History view but that only seems to show the Annotation for the current version.

Comment: @Dan "Link Editor with Selection" is supposed to keep the history updated depending of the file you are currently edited. Are you using Subversive or Subclipse?

Comment: @Dan then it would be interesting to check if Subversive (that I used for my answer) brings you the feature you want through the combination of Annotation View and History View.