# SVN revert just my changes on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, revert

I used Eclipse and just want revert my(old my changes) changes. Please any one can help. I am new to use Eclipse and SVN...

Comment: I used Eclipse and just want revert my(ONLY my changes) changes. Please any one can help. I am new to use Eclipse and SVN..

Comment: Which are you using Subversive or Subclipse?

Comment: Did you read [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983/rolling-back-bad-changes-with-svn-in-eclipse)?

Comment: Changes you've committed? Or changes in progress which have not been committed?